# Copy dynamic data range (from PivotTable) from one worksheet and paste to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro button on worksheet2, and my data (PivotTable) on worksheet1. I want to:

1. Push macro-button on worksheet2
2. Macro clears PivotTable and selects a certain field on worksheet1
3. Copy the PivotTable on worksheet1
4. Paste to a specific cell on worksheet2

My macro does everything but it does not copy the data from worksheet1, it copy's the data from worksheet2 for some reason. I have the code within a With statement, not sure why it's copying data from the activesheet (worksheet2).

```
Sub muniButton()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Refresh PivotTable and copy source data
    
    With worksheet1
        .PivotTables("inventoryPivot").ClearAllFilters
        .PivotTables("inventoryPivot").PivotFields("Type"). _
            CurrentPage = "REGIONAL"
        Range("P5:Q5", Range("P5:Q5").End(xlDown)).Copy
    End With
    
' Pasting source data

    worksheet2.Range("outputCorner").Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True   

End Sub
```

I'm not including `.` in front `Range("P5:Q5", Range("P5:Q5").End(xlDown)).Copy` because it gives an error. Shouldn't this copy data from worksheet1 since it's within the With statement? For some reason it copys the data from worksheet2 since it's the activesheet.

Thanks.

Comment: That's what the two `.`  are for - to scope the `Range()` calls to worksheet1.  FYI if you only had one `.` then that would have been the problem.

Comment: Hi Tim, which two `.` do i have? when I add `.` in front of `Range("P5:Q5", Range("P5:Q5").End(xlDown)).Copy` I receive an error. Should it copy the range within worksheet1 since it's within the With statement?

Comment: `.Range("P5:Q5", .Range("P5:Q5").End(xlDown)).Copy` see my first comment on your previous post.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy the entire pivot table you can use it's TableRange1 property.

```vb
    With worksheet1.PivotTables("inventoryPivot")
        .ClearAllFilters
        .PivotFields("Type").CurrentPage = "REGIONAL"
        .TableRange1.Copy
    End With
```

Note, if you have page fields and you also want to copy those replace TableRange1 with TableRange2.